# Form With Two Actions: Sends E-Mail and Redirects To PayPal

Tags: php, html, forms, paypal

I'm working on a PayPal form that when submitted, also sends an e-mail with information captured on a input field. The PayPal form works great on it's own and the PHP Mail action works on it's own as well.

However, I am unfamiliar with PHP and I can't seem to find a way to run both my PHP action and the redirect to PayPal link action when clicking the submit button. All help is greatly appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
  <!-- The select element is used by my mail.php -->
  <input name="name" required>
    <select name="priority" size="1" required>
      <option value="Low">Option1</option>
      <option value="Normal">Option 2</option>
      <option value="High">Option 3</option>
    </select>
  <input id="donate-amount" name="donate-amount" type="number" class="center-block donate-form" placeholder="Other Amount"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations" />
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="email@email.com" />
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donation Description">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
  <input type="hidden" name="tax" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
  <input id="amount" type="hidden" name="amount" value="15.00">

  <input name="submit" type="image" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/btn/png/btn_donate_92x26.png" /><span class="lazy_container" style="width: 1px;"><span class="lazy_preloader" style="padding-top: 100%;"></span><img width="1" height="1" alt="" src="plugins/system/tmlazyload/blank.gif" class="lazy" data-src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" border="0" /></span>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $priority = $_POST['priority'];
    $formcontent=" Donor: $name \n Priority: $priority \n";
    $recipient = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Donation";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
?>
```

Comment: They're not a donor at that point. You'll want to run the `mail` call when they come *back* from PayPal, or better yet, via PayPal's IPN system.

Comment: It's a custom client request. They don't want to submit anything to PayPal other than the donation amount which takes them to the page. However the mail.php captures what they selected in the select menu. It doesn't send the amount, because they aren't concerned with that. I agree with you on a logical standpoint, but this is what I need to do.

Comment: Then I suspect your best approach is to catch the form submit via JS, make an AJAX call, then re-trigger the form submit after your AJAX call does the mail send.